# Spring Data JPA and QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

I'm new to Spring data JPA and am trying to understand how to best use it with QueryDSL. Without QueryDSL, I would be able to simply create any queries in my SpringData interface with an @Query annotation.

In order to have the same experience using QueryDSL, from what I can see, I need to either create my own custom repository implementation and have my repo interface extend my custom implementation interface or put all my QueryDSL queries at a service layer which wraps my repo.

In the first case, I lose the ability to use any of the SD autogenerated methods (ex: findAll(QueryDSL predicate) ) in my custom repo since I don't have access to the actual repo object, and in the second case I am putting query logic at the service layer instead of at the repo layer.

Neither solution sounds particularly attractive to me.  Is there a 3rd way that is more appropriate?  Or am I misunderstanding how to properly use QueryDSL and Spring Data?

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the most convenient way is to let your repository interfaces simply extend `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` which adds the capability to simply pipe Querydsl `Predicate` objects into the repository and execute them standalone or alongside `Pageable` and `Sort` and the like.

If you really want to hide the combination of predicates into the repository layer (which is absolutely fine but actually serves a different purpose) you create a separate repository implementation class as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) and use `QueryDslRepositorySupport` as base class. In your implemented finder methods you can then just use the `from(…)`, `update(…)` and `delete(…)` methods of the base class to easily construct and execute queries using the Querydsl meta-model.

Comment: The matter is not `hiding the combination of predicates into the repository`, for me it's about adding `group by` and ... to my queries and execute them which only predicates don't seem to go near that

Comment: Unfortunately, `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` does not allow to use `groupBy` etc. Only the `where` part of the query. It's often is not enought. But custom repository impl with `QueryDslRepositorySupport` as base class is really good!

Comment: @azerafati, take a look at https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-jpa-querydsl, it might be what you are looking for.